$f$ is injective iff $f_{\text{median}} = f(\frac{a+b}{2})$ for non-constant functions $f$??
Definitions
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $b>a$ and let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous non-constant function. Define the function $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$g(t) := \int_{a}^{b} |t - f(x)| dx$$
Let $f_{\text{median}} = t_0$ such that $g(t_0) = \min\limits_{t \in [a,b]} g(t)$.
EDIT: If $f(x) = c$, for some fixed (but arbitrary) $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $f_{\text{median}} = c$.
Motivation
A general case (which works for every continuous function) is the following:
Let $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$, define $x_n = a + \frac{(b-a)n}{2N-1}$ for some $N \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Then,
$$f_{median} := \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \text{median} \{f(x_0), f(x_1), f(x_2), \cdots, f(x_{2N-1})\}$$
Fact: If $f$ is monotonic, then $f_{\text{median}} = f(\frac{a+b}{2})$. (The proof is left for the reader).
The information for this kind of idea came from Michael Penn's channel.
Question
Is it possible to find a function $f$ such that if for all (fixed but arbitrary) $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, the condition if $f_{\text{median}} = f(\frac{a+b}{2})$, then $f$ is injective on the interval $[a,b]$ is true? If not, what is one counterexample? I tried to prove or disprove it but I got stuck. However, I believe that the answer doesn't depend on the $f_{\text{mean}}$ anyway.
EDIT: I think that I proved that $f$ may not be injective but monotonic.
EDIT #2: I found a counterexample. Consider $f(x) = x^3-2x$ on the interval $[-8,3]$. You guys can check that $f(\frac{a+b}{2}) = f(-5) = f_{\text{median}}$, but $f$ is not monotonic. I believe there a infinitely many polynomials with $f(\frac{a+b}{2}) = f_{\text{median}}$ but $f$ is not  monotonic. You guys can play with this idea here on Desmos.

You must have made a mistake in the statement of the question ("Is it possible to find ..."). Because as it is written, one could just take any injective function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Unless I've made some error in my mind, the statement "$f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous and injective $\Rightarrow$ median is $f[(a+b)/2]$" is true. I'm just not sure if that is what you're asking.

@Stefan What I am trying to ask is that IF for all arbitrary (but fixed) $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we have  $f_{\text{median}} = f(\frac{a+b}{2})$ (for non-constant functions), then $f$ is injective on the interval $[a,b]$. Is that possible? If not find a counterexample.

In this question (comment above) $f$ need not have a domain exclusively to $[a,b]$. This function takes any domain $D$ to make $f$ continuous and non-constant.

You mean "injective on $D$", not "injective on the interval $[a,b]$", right? The answer is no, because $f$ could just be constant on a small interval contained in $D$. Maybe you want to replace "injective" by "monotone".

Alright! I changed it to $[a,b]$ instead of $D$.

There are several counterexamples. Here are a few:

$f(x) = x^3 - 2x^2 - x$ on the interval $[-7,3]$.

Consider now the piecewise function:
$$
\begin{equation}
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x^2, & -1 \leq x < 1\\
    -x+2, & 1\leq x \leq 3
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
on the interval $[0.6, 3]$

If $h: [-1,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x) = -f(x)$ on the same interval as number 2.


In fact more is true. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and $$S_{a,b}:= \{f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ is a function that is not monotonic, but } f(\frac{a+b}{2}) = f_{\text{median}}\}$$ Then, $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in [a,b]$, if $f \in S_{a,b}$ we have:

$f + c \in S_{a,b}$
$|f| \in S_{a,b}$
$-f \in S_{a,b}$
$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha f \in S_{a,b}$

$\\$ where $(f+c)(x) = f(x) + c, (\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x)$, so on and so forth.
